# PJSIP Integration proper guiding step to run in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, sip, pjsip

> I had tried to compile pjsip library.but getting error. when run

```
$ cd /pjproject-2.5.5
$ ./configure-iphone
//error: -bash: -bash: ./configure-iphone: Permission denied
$ chmod +x configure-iphone //then i tried this
$ ./configure-iphone
//error:-bash: ./configure-iphone: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.
```

> Please give me proper guide line by steps to
>   run pjsip ios project.

Answer (score 1):

To compile pjsip for iPhone

**1.** Download source code from one of the following link :

http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Download-Source

**2.** Create a new file *config_site.h* in the project folder */pjlib/include/pj/* with the following code:

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1 
#include <pjconfig_site_sample.h>
```

**3.** To Build PJSIP

Open terminal:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ ./configure-iphone
```

You may get the following problems:

**a) Permission denied**

```
Solution: preface the login with sudo 
or login as super user using su command and the type following command
   $ su
   Password:
   # chmod 777 configure-iphone
   # exit
```

**b) -bash: ./configure-iphone: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

(This error may come because in the configure-iphone file every line may have been appended by a character $ or may be a carriage return symbol)
        To check this do as:

```
$ vim configure-iphone
    (It wil open the vim editor)
    To see the last character press escape(ESC:)set list
    To quit vim press Esc:q
```

Then Eliminate

```
$ tr -d '\r' <configure-iphone >FILE.new
```

(It will create new file with name FILE. Now after that delete the configure-iphone file and rename FILE to configure-iphone using the following commands:)

```
 $ rm configure-iphone
 $ mv FILE.new configure-iphone
```

(Again confirm that new created file has 777 permission if no then assign from su- super user)

```
$ ./configure-iphone
```

Again there may be error in ./configure-iphone: 
**Permission denied**

```
Solution : Assign 777 permission to the whole folder. 
   - $ cd .. (Go to the parent folder in which the PJSIP folder lies)
   - $ su (login as super user)
   - # chmod 777 * (It will assign 777 permission to the whole folder and its content)
Alternatively:
   - $ chmod u+x configure-iphone
```

Again run $ ./configure-iphone command. This time every thing should work fine.

**4.** To make

```
make dep && make clean && make
```

Source: http://gaurav-iphone.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/compiling-pjsip.html

Comment: Thanks for the deep understanding post. Now can you please tell me how to use these libs in xcode project how to link and What is want to make a carthage file

Answer (score 0):

To compile pjsip for iOS you need to execute following commands:

1. cd path_to_pjsip
2. ./configure-iphone ( or sudo ./configure-iphone )
3. make dep && make clean && make ( or sudo make dep && make clean && make)

That's it, you now have pjsip compiled for armv7 architecture. You may also look in this tutorial for more details: http://www.xianwenchen.com/blog/2014/06/09/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-app-with-pjsip-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

To integrate PJSIP with Xcode,follow these steps.

**step 1:** **Download PJSIP project** file(.tar.bz2 or .zip file) from this link http://pjsip.org/download.htm

**step 2:** **Extract** the files into your Required path of your MAC.

**step 3:** Open the project folder and you will see,there is pjlib folder is there. Go to the Path **pjlib/include/pj/** and create **config_site.h** file and PASTE the following contents into the file.

```
 #define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
 #include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

**step 4:** Now save and close the file. And Open the Terminal Now.

**step 5:** Open your project path in the terminal by cd /your_pjsip_path/

For Example: **cd /Desktop/pjsip_2.5.5/**

**step 6:** Now build and configure project by following commands.

**step 7:** `./configure-iphone`

**step 8:** `make dep && make clean && make`

step 9: Now you can oepn the project using xcode 7 by Go to the path `/pjsip_folder/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/pjsua.xcodeproj` and open with xcode.

**(or)**

To integrate PJSIP Library with Xcode 7, you must follow official PJSIP instructions from their official website.

Source:https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone